# There exists $c > 0$ such that $M(d)>cd$ for "big enough" $d$ and convex function $M(d)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given a function $M(d)$ such that $M(d)\geq 0$ and there is a $d_0$ such that $M(d_0) = 0$ which also satisfies the following inequality for $0 < d_1 < d_2 < d_3$
$$
(d_3 - d_1) M(d_2) \leq (d_3 - d_2)M(d_1) + (d_2 - d_1)M(d_3)
$$
I am trying to prove that there exists a number $c$ such that $M(d) > cd$ for all "big enough" $d$.

---

I tried to somehow "brute force" the result from the inequality. By choosing $d_0 < d' < d$ we have that:
$$
(d - d_0)M(d') \leq (d-d')M(d_0) + (d' - d_0)M(d)
$$ 
But we know that $M(d_0) = 0$. So by rearranging the inequality we get:
$$
\frac{(d-d_0)M(d')}{d'-d_0} \leq M(d)
$$
I thought that I could turn the left side into something multiplied by $d$ and call that something $c$. Clearly, I hae some terms more than I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if $M(d) = 0$ everywhere? Or $M(d) = \max (0, -d)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Of course, if $M(d) = 0$ for all $d \ge d_0$ then the desired estimate cannot hold. So let's assume that there is
$$
 0 < d_0 < d' \text{ with } M(d_0) = 0 < M(d') \, .
$$
Then – as you correctly calculated – for all $d > d'$
$$
 M(d) \ge \frac{d-d_0}{d'-d_0} M(d')
$$
and since
$$
 \frac{d-d_0}{d'-d_0} > \frac{d}{d'}
$$
we have $M(d) \ge \frac{M(d')}{d'} \cdot d$ for $d > d'$.